# OpenERP StackExchange site in Area51

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, area-51, specific-proposal

There is a proposal for an OpenERP StackExchange site currently in Area51.  It is currently stuck in the "needs more questions with 10 votes" stage.

On StackOverflow there are currently 975 OpenERP questions.

Is there some way to use the StackOverflow questions to get the OpenERP site up and running?  If you need a volunteer, I volunteer.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done - the questions are posted on SO by many people and no doubt have answers and votes.  I would imagine that it'd be a very bad thing to actively tout the proposal in answers and comments as well.

Probably the best thing to do is for you or anyone involved with the proposal to put a link and a description in your profile.  If people are interested then they will help out the proposal.